# Как связать  treeview с БД Access в Delphi?

Tags: access, delphi, база-данных

Есть дерево с компонента treeview в Delphi и база данных Access. Как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на дочерние или родительские элементы выводилась нужная информация?

Comment: ADO Data components?

Comment: да. . . . .

Answer (score 1):

Давно не ковылял Делфю, но попробую - для работы с контролами для отображения данных, сами данные должны быть представлены в форму древовидных структур т.е. в форме (IDParentItem, IDItem, Data) где IDParentItem - ключ родительского обьекта,  IDItem - ключ самого обькта, Data - информация для отображения.

Есть два пути решения Вашей задачи:

1) использование готового контрола используемого для отображения древовидных данных - к примеру пак DevExpress - там есть изящный [контрол](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumTreeList/) но за деньги, либо контрол из пака [JVCL](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/) - бесплатная библиотека всевозможных вкусностей для Дельфи. В обеих контролах достаточно иметь данные представленные в виде указанном мною в начале

2) Использовать стандартный контрол из Дельфи но с допиленной логикой - т.е. в начале загружаем только те сущности у которых в исходных данных отсутствуют родительские ключи. Потом при попытки раскрыть элементы контрола - проверить если у прикрепленного элемента данных есть дочерние элементы и отобразить их. И так по рекурсии и итерации. Геморно, но повышает уровень красноглазия в Дельфе.

Надеюсь помог.